# Derivative of the curve and its meaning

Tags: limits, derivatives, tangent-line, secant

The derivative of the function $y=x^2$ is $y=2x$.
So, does this mean that the derivative is the equation of the secant of the curve which can be modified to tangent at a point?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is the slope of the tangent in the $x-y$ plane: $f'(x_0)$ is the slope of the tangent to $f$ at the point $(x_0,f(x_0))$

Comment: But when i plot those in general ,without considering any individual point,the derivative cuts the curve at two points so its a secant ryt?,when i consider a point the secant line changes to tangent line,thanks for clarifying my doubt

Comment: As written in this answer, the derivative is only the value of the **slope** of the tangent. If you don't place the tangent at the right place it has no meaning of course.